# What to consider when choosing between f-divergence measures? (e.g.: kl-divergence, chi-square divergence, etc.)

Tags: distance, kullback-leibler, divergence, jarowinkler-distance, f-divergence

I have some baseline population, and I have a non random sample from that population. For both the population and the sample I have observation of some measure (for simplicity, let's say age).

I would like to measure how "un-similar" my sample is from the target population, and would like to use a divergence measure (in which the $P$ is the distribution of age in the population and $Q$ the distribution of age in the sample).

I know that the [f-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) includes various known options such as [kl-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), chi-square divergence, and others.
But it's not clear to me how to prefer or decide which [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)) to choose. Are there some known considerations on when using one over the other is beneficial? (in terms of interpretation, or decision making?)

For example, I know that various machine learning algorithms might use kl-divergence (or cross entropy) for optimizing, but it's not clear to me why that is better or worse then, say, chi-square divergence.

Thanks.

Comment: Cross-entropy loss is intimately related to (and equivalent to) maximum likelihood estimation of logistic regression parameters.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482888/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-understand-how-kl-divergence-differs-from-other-simil

Comment: How are you planning to use the measure of divergence? Without that there’s not much basis for a choice.

Comment: @MattF. - you can think that I have two populations, and I wish to compare the distance of their distributions on many dimensions. That would later be used to rank dissimilarity of the two population across dimensions. The thing is that I am trying to understand how each of the distance measures might be interpreted, so to understand how each of them can be interpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should consider three factors when choosing a divergence:

1. The assumptions you take on $P,Q$ as probability measures: In [Hellinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance), for example, you need $P,Q$ to be absolutely continuous w.r.t a third probability measure $\lambda$. In that context, KL divergence is apparently less "demanding", only assuming $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $Q$.
2. Desired divergence properties: For example, $\chi^2$ and KL are not symmetric, while [Jensen-Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) is.
3. The intended use of the divergence: For example, when testing $H_0:X\sim P$ against $H_1:X\sim Q$, a useful divergence would be the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), where $f(x)=0.5|x-1|$ and $TV(P \| Q)=0.5\int{|dP-dQ|}$. When considering a quadratic loss, the Le Cam divergence fits, where $f(x)=0.5\left(\frac{1-x}{x+1}\right)$ and $LC(P \| Q)=0.5\int\frac{(dP-dQ)^2}{dP+dQ}$. You can find out some more [here](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/itbook-export.pdf) (see Section 7).

Comment: I believe your first point, regarding the Hellinger distance, is misleading. First, the Hellinger distance is an f-divergence, meaning it can be defined without reference to a third dominating measure. Second, such a measure is always guaranteed to exist -- as mentioned in your link, $\lambda = P + Q$ is one such example.